# Changement d'orthographe des participes présents et adjectifs

Tags: prononciation, orthographe, adjectifs, participe-présent

Page 49 dans *Advanced French Grammar*, V. Mazet soutient ceci :

> A few present participles undergo a spelling change when they are used as adjectives or nouns. These include: —ant to —ent, —quant to —cant, and —guant to —gant.
>
> Il a eu une crisme d'asthme en se **fatiguant**.
> Faire la vaisselle n'est pas **fatigant**.

Puisque la prononciation me semble rester la même après ces transformations, à quoi servent-elles ? Pourquoi les participes présents subissent-ils ces modifications ? (La réponse simple est d'agacer les étudiants du français comme moi ?)

Comment: Non c'est justement pour aider les étudiants à comprendre que les deux mots ne jouent pas le même rôle dans ces deux phrases !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[fatigant](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fatigant) et [fatiguant](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fatiguant) sont des [homophones](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/homophone), de [catégories lexicales](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cat%C3%A9gorie_lexicale) différentes ([part of speech](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech)). Ils n'ont pas la même fonction syntaxique dans la phrase (bien qu'ils soient tous les deux liés au sens du mot *fatigue*).

Dans ce cas particulier, il y a deux [graphies](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/graphie) pour représenter ces deux mots ayant le même son :

- *fatigant* est un adjectif, et s'accorde en genre et en nombre (ex : des journées *fatigantes*);
- *fatiguant* est un participe présent, invariable (ex : se *fatiguant* rapidement, il décida d'abandonner).

Dans d'autres cas, deux mots ayant des catégories lexicales différentes peuvent être homophones **et** [homographes](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/homographe), exemple : [harcelant](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/harcelant), [changeant](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/changeant), [éprouvant](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9prouvant), etc.

Un autre cas semblable à "fatigant / fatiguant" est : [divergent](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/divergent) / [divergeant](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/divergeant), deux homophones, mais **pas** homographes.

Pour répondre à la question (à quoi servent-elles ?) : à rien de particulier, c'est ainsi.

Pourquoi le son [/o/](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/orthographe/le-son-o-95.php) peut être écrit : o, ô, au, aut, ault, eau, ... ? Une langue qui a une longue histoire peut avoir quelques bizarreries...

Answer (score 2):

Grevisse (*le bon usage*) cite une trentaine de cas où le participe présent se distincte de l'adjectif verbal correspondant par l'orthographe et n'en donne qu'une explication historique partielle (*les adjectifs qui se distinguent, par leur terminaison en -ent, des participes présents doivent leur forme aux participes présents latins auxquels ils on été empruntés.*)

À partir d'un verbe, on a donc normalement trois dérivés de fonction différente mais d'orthographe identique :

- l'adjectif verbal, qui peut avoir une orthographe différente, qui s'accorde et se comporte comme un adjectif plutôt qu'un verbe (pas d'objet direct, négation avec non-); normalement les adverbes précèdent les adjectifs verbaux; leur sens peut être modifié par rapport à celui du verbe (p.e. passif plutôt qu'actif, un *billet payant* ne paye rien mais doit l'être rien)
- le participe présent, qui est invariable, se comporte comme un verbe en étant nié avec ne, en pouvant avoir un complément d'objet direct; normalement les adverbes suivent les participes présents; (*Pierre payant son billet* équivaut plus plus ou moins à *Pierre qui paye son billet*)
- le gérondif, comme le participe présent est invariable et se comporte comme un verbe, ils sont souvent introduits par *en* et ont une fonction de complément de temps, de manière, ... plutôt que de qualifié le nom ou le pronom auquel ils se rapportent. (*En payant son billet, Pierre ...* équivaut plus ou moins à *Pendant qu'il payait son billet, Pierre ...*)