# Les mots « différant » et « différent »

Tags: vocabulaire, orthographe, adjectifs, participe-présent

Il est commun d’utiliser le mot *différent* lorsque deux choses ne sont pas les mêmes. Il  s’agit d’un participe du mot latin *difero*, à savoir *diferens*. Après avoir subis quelques changements, ces mots atteignaient la langue française sous l’apparence de  *différer* et *différent*.

J’ai pensé à une autre façon d’exprimer que deux choses diffèrent, à savoir au moyen du mot *différant*, le participe français. À mon avis, faire des mots à partir du vocabulaire courant vaut mieux qu’emprunter un mot d’une langue étrangère : Un emprunt n’a aucun rapport avec les mots qui appartiennent déjà à une langue. C’est pourquoi j’étudie ce mot.

On ne peut rien dire de son utilisation dans le langage parlé, puisqu’on ne peut pas entendre la différence. Quant à l’écrit, je ne vois jamais le mot *différant* dans un livre. Il semble que même les ressources en ligne se bornent au mot *différent*.

Maintenant, je voudrais savoir si ce mot sert à quelque chose en français. L'emploie-t-on pour souligner quelque chose, ou pour rapporter à quelque chose ? ou est-il inusité ?

Comment: Le mots *différant* et *différent*, différant principalement par leur fonction dans la phrase, ont une orthographe différente, mais n'entretiennent aucun différend ! Je pense que tu trouveras la réponse que tu cherches ici : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6723/changement-dorthographe-des-participes-pr%c3%a9sents-et-adjectifs. On marque cette question *doublon* ?